# Why does gcc have different formats for -I and -L

Tags: gcc

`man gcc` gives `-I dir` and `-Ldir`. Note that there is a space in the first option but not the second. Why do they differ?

Comment: The space is optional in both cases. I expect it's just an inconsistency in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way the documentation was written, I would say.

In both cases you can have the space or not between the option and the value.

In fact, *my* `gcc` man page (CygWin) has no space for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

GNU tools (through getopt) supports both the option-argument following immediately after the option and the option-argument being the next command line argument. i.e. -Ldir and -L dir are equivalent.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

> If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg.